# Как скриптом в Google Sheets удалить группировку столбцов/строк?

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, таблицы, google-sheets-api

Подскажите, как скриптом в Google Sheets удалить группировку столбцов/строк?
не удалить сгруппированные данные, а только отменить группировку!
я нашел код на другом сайте... но не знаю, здесь можно ссылки на сторонние ресурсы давать?!
я не могу понять тот код удаляет сгруппированные данные или только отменяет группировку...

[Возможное решение](https://reddeveloper.ru/questions/udalit-vse-sgruppirovannyye-stroki-stolbtsy-v-elektronnoi-tablitse-6kNEw)

Comment: `я не могу понять тот код` -мы тоже не можем понять, поскольку не видели. Код можно вставить в вопрос, также можно в вопрос добавить ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

код по ссылке работает, сейчас опробовал.
и удаляет именно группировку